# Find a set K of k vertices in a graph such that the distance between any vertex to the closest vertex in K is minimized

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

Given a graph with $V$ vertices and $k$, find a set $K$ of $k$ vertices of $G$. Let $c(v)$ be the distance (in BFS-like) of the vertex $v \in V$ to the closest vertex $u \in K$. How to choose the set $K$ such that the maximum $c(v) \forall v \in V$ is minimized?

This is like a dominating set, but each vertex covers a range of vertices, and we are interested in minimizing this range.

Comment: 1. In the first sentence, you say that $K$ is given, but in the third sentence you say you want to choose it.  Which is it?  I suspect the inputs are the graph and $k$, and the desired output is $K$.  I encourage you to edit the question to clarify.  2. Given that you mention the connection to dominating set, I presume you already know that this problem is NP-hard.  What kinds of answers are you looking for?  Practical algorithms?  (If so, can you give us any idea how large $k$ and $|V|$ typically are?)  Approximation algorithms?  Exponential-time exact algorithms?

Comment: 1. You are correct, I want to find K. 2. Anything

Comment: Have you searched for “minimum k-dominating set problem"? Have you read, for example, [Solving the k‑dominating set problem
on very large‑scale networks](https://doi.org/10.1186/s40649-020-00078-5)?

Comment: I'll take a look. Ty for the ref

Comment: @JohnL. By the way, if I want to find the biggest k-dominating set of cardinality $\leq k$ such that no 2 vertices in K are closer than $d$, do you have a reference?

Comment: I guess one could call it k-independent set